# IIS disappeared after update to insider build 14931

Tags: windows, iis

Today I updated my windows 10 Pro computer to Insider Build 14931. When update finished, I noticed IIS disappeared. I went back to `Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features` where i saw `Internet Information Services` was unchecked. I checked, it and got IIS back. The problem is that all the websites I created disappeared (websites folders and files, remain in my computer) and PHP & many extensions I had installed are no longer.
Of course, I can download them and reinstall, but I was looking if there is a shorter solution to it. Thank you.

Comment: Do you have any directories under `C:\inetpub\history\`? There may be backups of the main IIS configuration files which you can restore to at least get all the sites back.

Comment: I do have the `C:\inetpub\history`, but I do not know how to restore IIs with data that are inside.

Comment: Copy the latest files from `C:\inetpub\history` to `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config` `applicationHost.config` is the most important one.

Comment: Thank very very much. All my configuration is back... Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Backups of the IIS configuration may be stored under `C:\inetpub\history`, just copy the latest files to `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config`.